# have trouble when using goroutine in Golang

Tags: go, goroutine

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //-"time"
)

func main() {
    c:=make(chan int)
    for i:=0;i<1000;i++{
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(<-c)
        }()
    }
    for j:=0;j<1000;j++{
        c<-j
        //-time.Sleep(time.Second/100)
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it just print only about one hundred digitals.
Why it didn't print 1000 digitals?

But when i didn't comment the code in the picture, the result became what I expected. Where is the problem?

Comment: Add your code as text, not as image.

Comment: Maybe I know where the problem is.Because system call will cost a lot of time ,and the main function won't wait for so long time.

Answer (score 2):

[Goroutines are similar to 'background jobs'](https://golangbot.com/goroutines/):

> The main Goroutine should be running for any other Goroutines to run. If the main Goroutine terminates then the program will be terminated and no other Goroutine will run.

The 1000 goroutines waiting for a message on channel 'c' are running in the 'background'.  The main thread sends 1000 messages to channel 'c' and immediately terminates.

The 100 or so integers output will be nondeterministic, as each of your 1000 goroutines will only survive as long as it takes the main thread to send 1000 integers to channel 'c'. You need the main thread to wait for 1000 goroutines to finish.  Try using a `sync.WaitGroup` object:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    //-"time"
)

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    c:=make(chan int)
    for i:=0;i<1000;i++{
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(<-c)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    for j:=0;j<1000;j++{
        c<-j
        //-time.Sleep(time.Second/100)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.It's my first question on stackoverflow.You really encourage me to ask question here :D

Comment: this program is written upside down, it should not wait on value being pushed, but wait on values being read. Hence no need of a waitgroup.